# Atlassian account-id

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

Recently, due to the GDPR new regulations on privacy, Atlassian have deprecated their access method via API.

As of about 1 week from today, accessing using username/email and password will no longer work.

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-user-privacy-api-migration-guide/

The new access method is by use of an account-id instead of a username, and an API-KEY instead of a password.

Unfortunately, I am unable to get my hands on my account ID.

I have spent hours reading through the documentation, but am unable to figure out how to get it.

I have read through https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/where-can-i-find-my-Account-ID/qaq-p/976527
but the methods there don't get me the account id.

Please give me the simplest method to translate my username and password to my account id.

Comment: I am a bit confused when you said "accessing using username/email and password will no longer work", do you mean you can no longer use basic auth with username:password pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaken. The article doesn't say anything about deprecating the authentication method. They are just gonna stop exposing things like `username` and `userKey` in the API.

You should be able to get your `accountId` from [/rest/api/3/myself](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3#api-rest-api-3-myself-get)